# Do I need to replace these metal support posts?

Tags: structural, post, corrosion

I have these 3 permanent lally support posts in the basement:

[post #1](https://vid.me/UsWM)
[post #2](https://vid.me/AbNj)
[post #3](https://vid.me/x7uB)

[image] Closeup frame captured from video #1

Recently basement was flooded so I tore down drywall prepping things for remodel. It does appear that support columns have rust on them.

Do you guys think:

a) These columns need to be replaced?
or
b) I can just clean & repaint:
    + wire brush
    + [rust neutralizer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001DEL6J6)
    + [red oxide primer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0009XB3TU)

Comment: Will it be subjected to more moisture or flooding?  Is this a private residence, a commercial building, or some type of shared housing (condos, apartments, living group)?

Comment: It's surface rust so likely not affecting the structural integrity much at all (though do clean it up and re paint.)

Comment: @wallyk it's a private residence. A reo house I bought and now remodeling. Water exposure happened because house was left without electricity & sump pumps were not working during bank possession. So yeah - it there will be floods again - that will only happen because of no electricity and hopefully be short in time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: No.

If they ring when you tap them like you did in your video, then they are solid.

Sand them and paint them with a good rust inhibiting paint.

Comment: Agreed, those columns have a long way to go before the integrity fails. The plate, although not needed, can be cut back an inch or so to get the rust off and painted. If you want to go overboard, again I think the posts will last regardless, chip away a little concrete, no more than what the drywall and baseboard will recover. Paint that part of the post too if the paint is in trouble, after it dries, pour a little silicone based concrete sealer in the trough you created with the chisel and let it soak in. It may keep future moisture from attacking the posts.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was thinking as well. I'll sand & paint then.